# Como criar efeito hover com duas canvas sobrepostas com efeitos contrários?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, canvas

Código Anterior.

*Segue a baixo o exemplo do código:

[JSFiddle Antigo](https://jsfiddle.net/Wagnerdabu/7fq9g5e7/)

Novo código para quem quiser!

[JSFiddle Novo](https://jsfiddle.net/Wagnerdabu/hed227Lb/)

Comment: Tipo criar uma div e encaixar em geral e seletar no `css` ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7fq9g5e7/2/

Comment: Neste caso @VictorGomes não daria para fazer desse jeito, seria uma indo para cima e outra para baixo, mas como as tags são sobrepostas teria que fazer alguma coisa em jquery para quando passar o mouse na "menu-nav-first", ele faço um hover no sentido contrario referente a ela.